# particle object rotation beginner question

Tags: particles

I'm afraid to post such a noob question. using blender2.8

but I want to make scene in which so many dead leaves sitting on the ground like winter forest.
my particle settings are foloowing:

==========

Type:Hair

▼Emission
 ▼Source:
Random　 ☑

▼Rotation:
Orientation Axis:   Normal
Randomize:5

▼Object:
GlobalCoordinates:   ☑

▼Rotation:
Orientation Axis:   Normal
Randomize:5

▼Render:
Render As:      Object

==========

kinda expected, most of the leaves are not sitting on , or lying down on the ground, but they are standing..

How do I get leaves lying over the ground and still leaves are rotating just only horizontally with randomized.[image: please do not rotate vertically like this image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the origin of the leaf object is at the bottom(so try to set the origin at the bottom of this leaf object). Also, try to rotate the original leaf object(experiment with the rotation of the leaf object you will get an idea about it). I think you know how to change the origin of the object.

Comment: solved !
thank you very much for help me.

Comment: It is good to hear that the problem has been solved.